# Не срабатывает prepare() в PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
switch($spinneritem)
{
    case 0:
        $query = "SELECT FLIGHTS.NUM, FLIGHTS.START_TIME, FLIGHTS.AIRPORT_TARGET FROM FLIGHTS
                            INNER JOIN STARTINGS ON STARTINGS.FLIGHT_NUM=FLIGHTS.NUM
                            INNER JOIN PLANES ON STARTINGS.PLANE_CODE=PLANES.PLANE_CODE
                            WHERE PLANES.TYPE= ? ";

        break;
}

try {
    $dbh = new PDO('*;charset=UTF8', *);

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute($value);
    $res = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
    $ret = json_encode($res);
    file_put_contents('debug.txt', $stmt->queryString."\n", LOCK_EX | FILE_APPEND);
    file_put_contents('android.txt', $res[0]." - returned value \n", LOCK_EX | FILE_APPEND);
```

В `debug.txt` записывается знак вопроса вместо значения, которое надо подставить. В returned value также ничего не идёт (хотя при вводе в консоли запрос даёт результат). `$value` строковое значение.
Соответственно в ошибки тоже записывается

> PDOStatement::execute() expects parameter 1 to be array.

Comment: вам черным по белому пишут, что передать надо не `$value` а `[$value]`, вы читаете вообще сообщения об ошибке?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> PDOStatement::execute() expects parameter 1 to be array.

в переводе звучит как *"Метод `execute()` ожидает в качестве первого параметра **массив**"*, 
вы же пишите

> `$value` строковое значение

Очевидно, решение имеет вид

```
$stmt->execute([$value]);
```

Comment: Спасибо, это невнимательность. Просто до этого работал с mysqli, там так работает.

Comment: @FoGezz тогда [примите ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: Принял конечно, нужно 5 минут было сначало подождать :)

Comment: за что минуса то, хоть потрудитесь объяснять (:

Comment: @teran, это адепты mysqli пытаются препятствовать переманиванию людей.